# How prevent Chrome mobile routing packets through US Compression proxy

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching, redirect

I'm debugging an API on my home development environment with the IP range `192.168.0.0-255`.
I'm in Australia (relevant for reasons below), the API's written in PHP, and I'm running Apache.

My server IP = `192.168.0.20`
My router is configured to forward HTTP requests to this IP.
My router's internal IP is `192.168.0.1` and external IP is, for this example, `123.123.123.123`

For the following cases:

1. Laptop, all browsers, over wi-fi
2. Android tablet, all browsers, over wifi
3. Android phone, using Internet browser, over wifi

the server detects `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 123.123.123.123`.
The latency is effectively zero and no caching occurs. So far, all as expected.

However, when I submit the same query from an Android mobile phone (assigned the IP of `192.168.0.10`) in Chrome over the same wi-fi connection, the server detects:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']: 123.123.123.123
$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']:       123.123.123.123
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] :         66.249.84.217`
```

The `'REMOTE_ADDR'` also takes on the values `66.249.84.223` and `66.249.84.229`

There is a delay of ~400ms and my API is being cached - hence not returning correct/latest values.

Relevant parts of HTTP header:

```
Forwarded: for=123.123.123.123
Scheme: http
Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
```

I see `66.249.84.0-255` belongs to Google, and understand why compression may often be useful in mobile context. But in my case I'd rather avoid the extra latency of a round-world-trip.

When I run the same queries over HTTPS, no re-routing through Googles's servers occurs.

Is there any way to avoid Chrome mobile re-routing my packets?

Comment: Note: [tag:google-chrome-app] is NOT for the mobile Chrome app.

Comment: Do you have "Reduce data usage" enabled within the browser? If so, that's likely what's causing this.

Comment: @admdrew yes you are right - toggled off and behavior is back as expected. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is, presumably, being routed through Google's [Data Compression Proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression).

Since Google does not try to hijack your SSL certificates, no such rerouting is being done for SSL connections.

On the client side, a user can simply disable this in settings with **Settings > Bandwidth Management > Reduce data usage**.

On the server side, it's too late to "undo" the routing, though you can indicate with a `Cache-Control: no-transform` header that you don't want your response transcoded.

Comment: Hello, `header("Cache-Control: no-transform");` for PHP is not working.
My page is still routed via proxy.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Developer Docs:

As a site owner, how do I opt-out from content optimization?
Data compression proxy respects the standard Cache-Control: no-transform directive. Site owners can mark individual resources with this directive and the proxy will pass them through directly to the mobile browser.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Comment: That doesn't make you opt out of proxying the requests (it's technically too late at that point anyway) - just stops Google transcoding the response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same answer for me. I have a network camera in New Zealand I access from Canada. I noticed a bunch of suspicious access in the Access Log in the range 66-xx-xx-xx, and believing the camera had been hacked I immediately added an access denial for that range (at the time I knew the range was owned by google ... but as far as I was concerned at the time it could have been a cloud machine of unknown purpose.)

Then noticing I could no longer access the netcam on chrome on my mobile (but could on the default browser, and any windows browser) It became clear that there was some kind of proxy in the middle. Further research led me here.

Here's some more info -
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Turning off Reduce Data Usage in chrome settings immediately restored access to my netcam

I have to wonder what's in it for google ? what valuable info are the mining from my traffic as it passes through their proxy?